# Converting from String^ to String*

Tags: pointers, c++-cli

I'm currently having a small issue which i thought would be easy, but not, so,(maybe it is easy, but i don't know) i need to convert a String^ into a String^* so basically a string pointer, small snippet of code:

```
ARPLC_command_byuser = textBox1->Text;
```

I've already tried various of methods, but all seem to fail(well, they don't, i do).

If you have any idea, please tell me what to do.

Comment: Let us see the code you have tried

Comment: String^ is already a reference, why do you need a pointer to it, what are you trying to do? Do you want to convert from `String^` to `std::string` or `wchar_t*`?

Comment: @sblom - Didn't know they used the ^ syntax in C++/CX, I might have jumped the gun on the retagging.

Comment: Declaration:
String^ *ARPLC_command_byuser;

Comment: A pointer to a .net managed pointer? That doesn't seem you'd really want that.

Comment: @pstrjds, I'm pretty sure they do--it has struck me as superficially quite similar even though things don't really work quite the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible.  A managed object is moved around in memory when the garbage collector compacts the heap.  Which will invalidate any pointer.  This is the primary reason that C++/CLI uses the ^ hat to indicate object references, they are pointers under the hood that the garbage collector can recognize and update when the object is moved.

Technically it is possible to *pin* a managed object to ensure that it doesn't get moved.  Something you can do with pin_ptr<> or GCHandle::Alloc().  This should be avoided.  Convert the managed string to a native pointer by copying it into unmanaged memory using the Marshal class.